# IntelliJ IDEA html open in browser/preview opens up wrong website

Tags: html, intellij-idea

I have 3 web modules under a project folder, each have a html file named index.html

I was just working on the html file in the 3rd web module, and I tried to open the html through IDEA in browsers and its build-in preview, but found that the preview shows the html file in the 2nd web module.

Then I go to the html file in the 1st web module to try to open that one instead, but it also opens up the html file in the 2nd web module.

I have tried to close tabs and reopen the project, and also clear cashes in browser, but none works.

I tried both using the pop-up and from the toolbar to open up preview, but they shows the same result.

And the weird thing is that when I was working on the second module (at that time I'm already done working on the first module), the preview just show its html file successfully, so I didn't notice the problem until now.

Do anyone know how to solve this?

__
UPDATE: I tried changing the name of the html file, and the preview shows the correct website now, but the website background is still the same as the second html, so I guess there must still be something wrong. They are in completely different module and the background image is under the 2nd module, I don't even know why the html file in the 3rd module can access that image.

I tried to open up the html file just by clicking on the file from Finder, and everything is correct. So it's still the problem with IDEA I guess?

Answer (score 0):

The built-in web server serves files from `http://localhost:63342/<project name>/path/from/content/root`, if you have multiple same/named files with similar paths, the arbitrary file will be served
This is a known limitation. Related ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-36442/HTML-files-with-the-same-name-are-opened-from-the-first-project-in-case-of-multiple-attached-projects